# Is it correct to use "better+verb"?

Tags: grammar

When is it correct to use "better+verb", for example which one of following sentences are correct?

> It better helps [me to prepare than something else].
>
> It better makes sense [than something else].
>
> It better matches the others.
>
> You will better understand it if you pay more attentions.

...where better means "more", not "had better" or "better" as verb.

Comment: Only the third sentence seems grammatically correct to me... Better is often used as a comparative term "_It helps better_ than..."

Comment: @JohnS, you might also be interested in another SE site, http://ell.stackexchange.com, where people teach and discuss the foundations of English grammar. You'd likely get an even more informative answer to this question there.

Comment: Better suited to http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ajcr Thanks, that's what I meant, but can better come before verb?

Comment: John, the short answer is **no**: *helps* cannot precede the verb in the kind of situations you're asking about (with the usual caveat that English is a bottomless sea of variation and nuance, so, for example, while your "*better helps*" and "*better makes*" are impermissible, "*better matches*" is perfectly fine. That's English for you.)

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for help and suggestion. I wasn't aware of ELL when I posted this question and even now I'm not sure if this question better suited there or here. Anyway, in your example "better suited" does better stands for "had better + infinitive without to" or does it mean "more" as adverb? (And did you mean "_better_ cannot..." by "_helps_ cannot..." in last comment?)

Comment: @John, yes, I meant "*better* cannot..." (sorry for the error). In the case of "*better matches*", *better* means *more*. I could say this question "is *better suited* to ELL", or "it *better matches* the charter of ELL [than ELU]". But I **cannot** say "ELL *better helps* people with these kinds of questions", nor can I say "putting 'better' after the verb *better makes sense* [than having it precede the verb]".

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, so do you have any idea why "better matches" is correct, but "better helps" is not?  Is there any grammar point here to consider for other verbs?  And what about "it better suites to ELL"?

Comment: Ah, "why is *better matches* correct?" is an entirely different (and on-topic) question! Let me edit your question to ask that (and after I'm done you'll see the difference between questions suited to EL&U vs ELL).

Comment: @Dan Bron "to better help him" has 214 000 Google hits, eg '... desire to understand my son in order to better help him succeed.' Obviously, 'to better help him play' and 'to help him play better' are not equivalent. I'm happy with 'to better help' most of the time, but not with 'to better make'. Sadly, there are **more** Google hits for the latter.

Comment: @Edwin: "to better help" is a simple split infinitive, which is a different situation. See the updated question.

Comment: @Dan I've not seen any rule saying that the forward-medial (ie before the verb) position is _wrong_ for 'better' with say 'help'. Here is an [admittedly rare] example of a non-infinitival usage from the internet: 'But it would have been nice had he better helped a school that worship[p]ed him then and still does.' I'm happy with this, though it's a very formal register. I'd accept 'only very rarely' rather than 'never'.

Comment: @Edwin, that example would be a lot more compelling if it were in the present tense (preferably simple rather than progressive: "having multiple stomachs *better helps* ungulates process..."). That said "this usage is rare but not impossible" serves well as an answer, particularly if you can elaborate on why it's rare, and what the modę common construction is. I'd also encourage you to address a wider range of verbs, in particular John's original "better makes sense" (now a parenthetical example in the first sentence).

Comment: @Dan That sounds like a lot of analysis. I'm guessing that 'better' in the sense of 'more fittingly' more readily occurs before a verb (better matches, better suits, better fits(!)) (than 'better' in the more general sense (?better helps. ?/*better makes), but that there is 'usage creep' so that 'better helps' say is not considered unallowable.

Comment: @edwin It certainly would be a lot of analysis, which is why I only clarified the question, rather than attempting an answer :) That said, the (relevant) examples in the original question (before my edits) would be interpreted by native speakers as incorrect and likely due to someone having English as a second language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the link, it's interesting, but please see my original question and feel free to edit the question instead of voting to close it.

Comment: I rolled back to my original question.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62315/shall-i-use-better-understand-or-understand-better

Answer (score 2):

Your examples are examples of the use of 'better' as a straightforward adverb.  Though like most comparative adverbs, it would usually follow the object, rather than preceding the verb.

`It better shows the color of your eyes` would usually be `It shows the color of your eyes better [than the other options]` in America.  Your usage is not outside some idiom, it is just so close to a common idiom that people avoid it.

OTOH two of your examples are off-center from another idiom: 'sense', 'help' and other pure virtues have a *quantity*, and not a quality.

Something does not 'make sense well', so it cannot 'better' do so.  It 'makes a lot of sense'.  Similarly something 'helps a lot' and does not 'help well'.  All sense is good, and so it all help, there are only degrees.  (There is an exception where one mechanism helps or makes sense of the same thing in a way more fitting to some situations than others, but it is not relevant to normal speech.)

Matching has a quality, as do most more-active verbs.  So one thing can better match another than other options.  Showing, explaining, etc. can be done well or poorly.  So 'better + verb' makes sense with the right kinds of verb.

Comment: Thanks, helpful. So what about for example "I will chose X, because it better helps me than Y."?

Comment: That is the exception that I dismissed in parentheses above.  You cannot cover all bases.  It seldom comes up in normal speech because folks would ordinarily say 'it helps me more'.

Comment: Also, just sliding the comparative back before the verb like that slows people down.  Splitting up "better than" is proper, but may feel pretentious.  It is grammatically smoother (adverb + verb is nice) but it separates the parts of the more important construction (comparative + compared).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget, the "it" is one thing - singular

> It better help!
>
> It better make sense!
>
> It better match the others!

It's that simple!

Here's a popular song from 1981 where the lyrics plays on the colloquialisms "you better" and "you bet!"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AuVfIP9F2Y

---

If you're asking about the "other" direction:

> It helps me to prepare, better than, some-other-thing.
>
> It makes better sense, than, some-other-thing.
>
> It better matches the others....
>
> ... you could mean either:
>
> It matches the XYZ, better than, the others match the XYZ.
>
> or
>
> It matches all the others, better than, some-other-thing.

Comment: +1. The answer would be even better if incised some discussion of "it better" vs "it *had* better", and the semantic mplications of the matter.

Comment: Thanks, however I didn't meant "had better", I have updated the question.  That's why I used helps/makes/matches.

Comment: @johns, thanks for the clarification. Based on the extended examples, I'd say ***no**, the sentences are not grammatical and don't make sense (and as a side-effect, Joe's answer here no longer applies). There are other ways to express the same ideas, though as I said, that's a question  better suited to our [sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hi John - again you should go to ELL (as Dan explains).  Note that all question about "multiple meanings!" are just closed.  It's utterly normal in English that sentences are ambiguous, and can only be understood, by context.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word 'more' is the word you are looking for on the first two, here:

It helps me more.

It makes more sense

EDIT:

Better refers to an increase in quality while more refers to an increase in quantity.

If you say something helps you better, then you are saying the quality of help is greater when compared to something else.

If you say something helps you more, you are saying you received a greater amount of help than something else.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, however my question is if better+verb is correct or not and I would like to learn the grammar usage of better.  My question is not how to communicate the meaning.

Comment: I understand and have edited my response. Is this more what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks, but not really, my question is if better can come before verb: "better+verb". Please see question comments.

Comment: By the way, while in my question I have already mentioned that "where better means more" how could I be looking for "more"?! :)